# python method is not called

Tags: python, scrapy

I have following class method in a scrapy spider. `parse_category` yields a Request object that has callback to `parse_product`. Sometimes a category page redirects to a product page. So here I detect if a category page is a product page. If it is, I just call the `parse_product` method. But for some reason it does not call the method.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        anchors = hxs.select('//div[@id="panelMfr"]/div/ul/li[position() != last()]/a')
        for anchor in anchors[2:3]:
            url = anchor.select('@href').extract().pop()
            cat = anchor.select('text()').extract().pop().strip()
            yield Request(urljoin(get_base_url(response), url), callback=self.parse_category, meta={"category": cat})

    def parse_category(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        base_url = get_base_url(response)

        # check if its a redirected product page
        if (hxs.select(self.product_name_xpath)):
            self.log("Category-To-Product Redirection")
            self.parse_product(response)  # <<---- This line is not called.
            self.log("Product Parsed")
            return

        products_xpath = '//div[@class="productName"]/a/@href'

        products = hxs.select(products_xpath).extract()
        for url in products:
            yield Request(urljoin(base_url, url), callback=self.parse_product, meta={"category": response.meta['category']})

        next_page = hxs.select('//table[@class="nav-back"]/tr/td/span/a[contains(text(), "Next")]/text()').extract()

        if next_page:
            url = next_page[0]
            yield Request(urljoin(base_url, url), callback=self.parse_category, meta={"category": response.meta['category']})

    def parse_product(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        base_url = get_base_url(response)

        self.log("Inside parse_product")
```

In the log I see `Category-To-Product Redirection` and `Product Parsed` is printed but `Inside parse_product` is missing. Whats did I do wrong here?

```
2013-07-12 21:31:34+0100 [example.com] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/category.aspx> (referer: None)
2013-07-12 21:31:34+0100 [example.com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.example.com/productinfo.aspx?catref=AM6901> from <GET http://www.example.com/products/Inks-Toners/Apple>
2013-07-12 21:31:35+0100 [example.com] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/productinfo.aspx?catref=AM6901> (referer: http://www.example.com/category.aspx)
2013-07-12 21:31:35+0100 [example.com] DEBUG: Category-To-Product Redirection
2013-07-12 21:31:35+0100 [example.com] DEBUG: Product Parsed
2013-07-12 21:31:35+0100 [example.com] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

2013-07-12 21:31:35+0100 [-] ERROR: ERROR:root:SPIDER CLOSED: No. of products: 0
```

Comment: You say "Same way parse_category yields to parse_product." But parse_category gets indirectly called by yielding a Request whose callback eventually calls parse_category; there's nothing even remotely yield-related with the call to parse_product. So, what does that "same way" mean, and what does the "yield" have to do with it? Or is this not the actual code that you're asking about?

Comment: `hxs` and `base_url` are local variables. I suspect you don't want them to be local variables. If they need to be instance attributes, you want `self.hxs` or `self.base_url`.

Comment: It's odd that you're seeing the logs around the `parse_product` call, but not the logs from inside the call. Are you sure there isn't some other definition of the `parse_product` method overriding this one?

Comment: @abarnert I was wrong. I am removing it.

Comment: @user2357112 No no other `parse_product` is there. only one